# Юнит Тесты для Калькулятора

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

**Добрый день на другом вопросе помогли, с решением калькулятора всем за спасибо за помощь шас у меня такая задача написать Юнит тесты для калькулятора написал тест кейсы и методы для проверки, но при запуске код не запускается, не знаю почему.**   [image: Ошибка 1]   [image: Ошибка]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                double a, b = 0;
                char z;
                Console.Write("Введите 1 число ");
                a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Введите действие (+, -, *, /, s(Корен)) ");
                z = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (z != 's')
                {
                    Console.Write("Введите 2 число ");
                    b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                switch (z)
                {
                    case '+':
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", a, b, a + b);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}={2}", a, b, a - b);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", a, b, a * b);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        try
                        {
                            if (b == 0)
                                throw new DivideByZeroException();
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", a, b, a / b);
                        }
                        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Делить на ноль нельзя");

                        }
                        break;
                    case 's':
                        Console.WriteLine("Корен({0})={1}", a, Math.Sqrt(a));
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnitTestProject5
{
    class Logic
    {
        public double Sum(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
        public double Diff(double a, double b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
        public double Mult(double a, double b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
        public double Div(double a, double b)
        {
            return a / b;
        }
        public double Koren(double a)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(a);
        }
    }

}
```

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnitTestProject5;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    class Class2 : Logic
    {
        [TestCase(5, 7, 12)]
        [TestCase(1, 2.5, 3.5)]
        [TestCase(100, -1, 99)]
        [TestCase(10, -100, -90)]
        public void TestSum(double a, double b, double exp)
        {
            double act = Sum(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
        }
        [TestCase(8, 5, 3)]
        [TestCase(9, 12, -3)]
        [TestCase(25, 20, 5)]
        [TestCase(10, 2, 8)]
        public void TestDiff(double a, double b, double exp)
        {
            double act = Diff(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
        }
        [TestCase(2, 5, 10)]
        [TestCase(5, 3, 15)]
        [TestCase(12, 10, 120)]
        [TestCase(10, 3, 30)]
        public void TestMult(double a, double b, double exp)
        {
            double act = Mult(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
        }
        [TestCase(6, 2, 3)]
        [TestCase(133, 1, 133)]
        [TestCase(35, 5, 7)]
        [TestCase(220, 2, 110)]
        public void TestDiv(double a, double b, double exp)
        {
            double act = Div(a, b);
            Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
        }
        [TestCase(4, 2)]
        [TestCase(9, 3)]
        [TestCase(25, 5)]
        [TestCase(16, 4)]
        public void TestSqrt1(double a, double exp)
        {
            double act = Koren(a);
            Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос (кнопкой "править") информацию об ошибке. Что именно происходит, когда запускаете?

Comment: Каким образом вы их запускаете? "Run tests" или "Run unit tests" ?

Comment: аттрибут `TestFixture` поди потеряли

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил

Comment: @Sterlukin Run Unit Tests Юнит тесты отдельно запускаются но с калькулятором в месте нет

Comment: Нет никаких предложений ?

Comment: `Юнит тесты отдельно запускаются но с калькулятором в месте нет ` - модульные тесты всегда запускают отдельно от программы, они и не должны запускаться одновременно с тестируемой программой.

Comment: @Bulson а не как нельзя как-то это все вместе сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, вы хотите чего-то странного.

Модульные тесты используют только разработчики, они никогда не поставляются вместе с приложением конечному пользователю. Соответственно, юнит-тесты никак не должны запускаться вместе с приложением.

Причём *модульные* тесты пишутся для тестирования какого-либо *модуля*. В данном случае - калькулятора, а не всего приложения.

Вы поняли, что протестировать код, помещённый в метод `Main` не получается, поэтому выделили отдельный модуль `Logic`. Его нужно переименовать в "калькулятор":

```
public class Calculator
{
    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    public double Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    public double Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
    public double Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
    public double SquareRoot(double d)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt(d);
    }
}
```

Теперь сделаем юнит-тесты для этого модуля-калькулятора. Они должны быть в отдельной сборке (проекте).

Чтобы класс калькулятора был виден в тестах, нужно к проекту тестов добавить ссылку на сборку (Add Reference) с классом `Calculator`.

```
[TestFixture]
public class CalculatorTests
{
    [TestCase(5, 7, 12)]
    [TestCase(1, 2.5, 3.5)]
    [TestCase(100, -1, 99)]
    [TestCase(10, -100, -90)]
    public void Add_Numbers_ReturnsSum(double a, double b, double expected)
    {
        // Arrange
        var calc = new Calculator();

        // Act
        var actual = calc.Add(a, b);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
    [TestCase(8, 5, 3)]
    [TestCase(9, 12, -3)]
    [TestCase(25, 20, 5)]
    [TestCase(10, 2, 8)]
    public void Subtract_Numbers_ReturnsDifference(double a, double b, double expected)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator();

        double actual = calc.Subtract(a, b);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
    [TestCase(2, 5, 10)]
    [TestCase(5, 3, 15)]
    [TestCase(12, 10, 120)]
    [TestCase(10, 3, 30)]
    public void Multiply_Numbers_ReturnsProduct(double a, double b, double expected)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator();

        var actual = calc.Multiply(a, b);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
    [TestCase(6, 2, 3)]
    [TestCase(133, 1, 133)]
    [TestCase(35, 5, 7)]
    [TestCase(220, 2, 110)]
    public void Divide_Numbers_ReturnsQuotient(double a, double b, double expected)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator();

        double actual = calc.Divide(a, b);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
    [TestCase(4, 2)]
    [TestCase(9, 3)]
    [TestCase(25, 5)]
    [TestCase(16, 4)]
    public void SquareRoot_Number_ReturnsResult(double d, double expected)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator();

        double actual = calc.SquareRoot(d);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Я постарался дать именования, соответствующие [рекомендациям](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices)

Обратите внимание, у нас ещё нет приложения, которое использует калькулятор. А тесты уже можно прогнать.

Для работы тестов необходим NUnit3TestAdapter. Нужно установить либо расширение к Visual Studio, либо пакет в проект с тестами.

---

Перепишем код приложения, задействовав в нём наш калькулятор.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Введите 1 число ");
        double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Введите действие (+, -, *, /, s(Корен)) ");
        char operation = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.WriteLine();

        double b = 0;
        if (operation != 's')
        {
            Console.Write("Введите 2 число ");
            b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        var calc = new Calculator();

        switch (operation)
        {
            case '+':
                Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", a, b, calc.Add(a, b));
                break;
            case '-':
                Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}={2}", a, b, calc.Subtract(a, b));
                break;
            case '*':
                Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", a, b, calc.Multiply(a, b));
                break;
            case '/':
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", a, b, calc.Divide(a, b));
                }
                catch (DivideByZeroException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Делить на ноль нельзя");
                }
                break;
            case 's':
                Console.WriteLine("Корень ({0})={1}", a, calc.SquareRoot(a));
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

На всякий случай приложу скриншот Обозревателя решения. Видно, что тесты расположены в отдельном проекте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

Конечно, эти тесты по сути бесполезны, т. к. по сути они проверяют работу встроенных команд процессора, но для обучения годятся.

Гораздо более интересным вариантом является написание, например, калькулятора, который принимает параметры в виде строк текста, парсит и вычисляет. Или можно добавить отдельный класс парсера. И, естественно, покрыть их тестами.

А можно ли протестировать метод `Main` и вообще код, принимающий ввод пользователя? [Можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041611/5045688). Но там довольно сильное колдунство. Если есть желание - задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ но при запуске тестов выдает ошибку

Comment: "Возникли ошибки при Сборки Продолжить и выполнить тесты из последней успешной сборки " такая ошибка выбираешь да и ничего тесты просто не проходятся

Comment: @VenDETTA - Так ошибка-то какая? Приведите её текст.

Comment: @VenDETTA - установите пакет NUnit3TestAdapter и добавьте ссылку на сборку. Я дополнил ответ описанием

Comment: шас Добавлю фото для наглядности опять тоже самое ошибка

Comment: Добавил фото к вопросу

Comment: @VenDETTA - Повторяю в третий раз: покажите **текст** ошибки. Внизу VS есть Error List (Список ошибок) - скопируйте оттуда текст.

Comment: Да вот прикол в том что такой ощибки нету только это))) выскакивает и все

Comment: "Программа не содержит статического метода Main. Вот такая ошибка